use Hero in StatefulShellBranch with StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack via go_router
How to use Hero between pages from different StatefulShellBranch within a StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack?
I'm using go_router.
How to use Hero between pages from different StatefulShellBranch within a StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
